# Moderator problems

Tags: discussion, chat, moderators, abuse, ban

Earlier today on chat, a [certain mod](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/103081/hichris123) kept banning me from [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq), seemingly for fun. This is yet another example of a mod misusing their powers, and what can be done about it?

Some quotes from chat:

> @TheDoctor try to rejoin Charcoal HQ. :P
>
> @TheDoctor Try now. :P

And an explanation:

> I didn't ban you, I just ran a kick-ban script on Charcoal HQ for a minute.

Comment: If a mod is banning you, they're not doing it for fun.  I suspect there's more to the story than you're telling.

Comment: @fbueckert - http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15309208#15309208 and http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15309251#15309251

Comment: I don't think that says what you think it does.

Comment: He is not a moderator...

Comment: @animuson yes he is!

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15309263#15309263 afterward

Comment: Oh, apparently he is now. But he's also an owner of that room, and frankly, they can do whatever they want. They can ban you from the room for whatever reason and there's not really anything you can do about it. No moderator abuse here.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15310675#15310675

Comment: #moderatorproblems

Comment: Looks like he just ran a script that repeatedly kicks you from the room. It also looks like you were being star-happy-annoying.

Comment: @ɥʇǝS that's what we always do in the 2nd monitor

Comment: @TheDoctor Yes, pretty much what Seth said. I didn't want you to star everything in Charcoal HQ, and it wasn't meant to be "abuse" or anything.

Comment: I would have done that only if everyone had moved to Charcoal. which they didn't.

Comment: *"I didn't ban you, I just ran a kick-ban script on Charcoal HQ for a minute."* ... problem solved.

Answer (score 24):

1. All he did was run a little script for a minute. Don't you think you're overreacting just a bit?
2. As mentioned earlier, you were annoyingly starring tons of messages.
3. That chat room wasn't even one with major discussion. It is used as a "testing" room quite often (which you full well know).
4. There is absolutely no "abuse" happening. He could kick you just for mentioning puzzles (*ahem*  @hichris123) and that would be perfectly fine - it's his room.
5. Notice the ":P" emoticons in his messages? He clearly was doing this only lightheartedly, and again, this is a huge overreaction.